# _Batch_ priorities in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, rdbms, dbms

I would want to tag many queries and mostly materialised view refreshing tasks as low priority in my RDBMS, in the fashion I run the web browser on the local machine as low priority (because JS, CSS, animated GIF do not deserve CPU time slices), the same way I do for C/C++ software builds, using a `nice` on Darwin and Linux supervisors.

**Can I do that?**

**Can I do that in vanilla PostgreSQL?**

Could I even couple *initial* job prioritisation with increasing to normal priority after a given timeout? Highways as real world analogy: in a normal situation there are slow traffic lanes and fast traffic lanes; but in a dense traffic situation all lanes get relatively slow, then unless for a very specific exceptional emergency services *job* that appropriates the lane.

Is this an oversight for the need of another family of DBMS (o-o, columnar, dwh...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is talked about exhaustively on the wiki. You'll have to ask a more poignant question

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Priorities